Azure DevOps YAML template with stage parameter
I am trying to create a YAML template to extend from with a fixed stage "Deploy" (can not be modified by users, only pass params) and an optional stage "PreDeploy" that should be entirely provided by template users (if they want to add this stage).
To achieve this I am using a stage parameter, but seems that my syntax is not correct since I get some error when saving:
parameters:
- name: variableGroup 
  type: string
  default: PROD
- name: application
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: {}

stages:
- ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }}
- stage: 'Deploy'


Even when providing a fake stage as default parameter just to pass validation it still does not work:
parameters:
- name: variableGroup 
  type: string
  default: PROD
- name: application
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: 
    jobs:
    - job: DoNothing
      pool: default
      steps:
      - powershell: Write-host "Doing nothing"

stages:
- ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }}
- stage: 'Deploy'


What am I doing wrong?

Please edit your post and paste the code as text, not images. Screenshots with error messages are fine.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same YAML sample.
To solve this issue, you need to define the stage type parameter with the following format:
parameters:
  - name: application
    type: string
    default: test
  - name: PreDeployStage
    type: stage
    default:
      stage:
      jobs:
      - job: DoNothing
        pool: default
        steps:
        - powershell: echo "Do Nothing"

If you want to define empty value for stage type parameter, you can use the following format:
parameters:
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: 
     stage: 
     jobs:
     - job: 
   

YAML exmaple:
parameters:
- name: variableGroup 
  type: string
  default: PROD
- name: application
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: 
    stage: test
    jobs:
    - job: DoNothing
      pool: default
      steps:
      - powershell: Write-host "Doing nothing"

stages:
- ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }}
- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps: 
    - script: echo "1"

Result:



Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT works like a charm with a "fake" parameter but for the emtpy one I need to add the "pool: default" below "-job:" otherwise it fails when running

@Josto This pool value should be optional. The reason why the pipeline is failed when running is that you may have no access to use Microsoft-hosted agent. By default, it will use Microsoft-hosted agent. If you define the pool value to default, it will use self-hosted agent in your Default pool.
